Issue of 'failing to join a channel after 5 attempts' while creating a Hyperledger fabric-based test network in Ubuntu
While attempting to run a test network provided through the link https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html, the simulator generated an error as shown in the Image. , how may one resolve this issue?
I had attempted to shut down the network and re-launch it, but all to no avail, for example by restarting the network.

This can sometimes be caused by Docker volumes hanging around from a previous time the Fabric network was created. In this case, you can resolve it as follows:

Stop any running test network: ./network.sh down
Clean up Docker volumes: docker system prune --volumes

It is worth checking that your Fabric binaries are Docker images are at consistent versions. Also that you have the latest main branch version of the fabric-samples repository cloned locally, assuming you are working with the current Fabric release version. If you are working with an older (deprecated) Fabric LTS release, either update to the latest Fabric release or use the matching branch in the fabric-samples repository. For example, the release-2.2 branch for Fabric v2.2.
An additional step you can take if there is configuration state left on the local disk is to:

Clean any downloaded binaries and generated configuration using git clean -xdf at the fabric-samples repository root — note that this will delete any uncommitted content you that have created within that repository too!
Re-download the Fabric binaries, as described in the documentation.

